# Ican't remove item(product) in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to remove  item(product) in React-Redux`enter code here`

```
   ProdcutType.js
   export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART'
    export const REMOVE_ITEM = 'REMOVE_ITEM'
   ProdcutAction.js
    import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from "./ProductType";

    export const add_to_cart = (img, title, price) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        img, title, price
    }
}
export const remove_item = (index) => {
    return {
        type: REMOVE_ITEM,
        index
    }
}

   ProductReducer.js

   import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from "./ProductType";

    enter code hereconst initialState = {
    arrProdcut: [],
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART: return {
            ...state,
            arrProdcut: state.arrProdcut.concat({
                img: action.img,
                title: action.title,
                price: action.price

            })
        }
        case REMOVE_ITEM: {
            // const item = action.item;
            // const new_state = { ...state };
            // delete new_state.arrProdcut[item];
            // return new_state;
            return {
                ...state,
                arrProdcut: state.arrProdcut.filter(item => item.id != action.index)
            }


        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rootReducer

cart.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { remove_item } from './redux/ProductAction'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Delete } from '@mui/icons-material';
import Cart2 from './Cart2';

function Cart(props) {
    const products = useSelector(state => state.arrProdcut)

    return (
        <Contanier>
            <Content>
                {products.map((item, index) => (
                    <Prodcts>
                        <Cart2 item={item} key={item.id} />
                    </Prodcts>
                ))}

            </Content>

        </Contanier >
    )
}

export default Cart

cart2.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { remove_item } from './redux/ProductAction'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Delete } from '@mui/icons-material';

function Cart2(props) {
    const { item, index } = props;


    return (
        <Contanier>
            <Content>
              
                <Prodcts>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Product</h3>
                        <Divimg>
                            <img src={item.img} />
                        </Divimg>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Name product</h3>
                        <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Price</h3>
                        <h4>${item.price}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Quantity</h3>
                        <input type="number" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Remove</h3>
                        <button onClick={() => props.remove_item(item.id)}>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </Prodcts>
            

            </Content>

        </Contanier >
    )
}

const MapToDispatch = dispatch => {
return {
    remove_item: (id) => dispatch(remove_item(id))
} } export default connect(null, MapToDispatch)(Cart2)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Hi, try logging and paste the result.......

case REMOVE_ITEM: {
            return {
                ...state,
                arrProdcut: state.arrProdcut.filter(item => {console.log(item.id,action.index); return item.id != action.index)}
            }
        }